# irbで2回以上loadすると失敗する

Tags: ruby, python, irb

rubyのirbでrubyのコードを2回以上loadすると失敗します。
なぜなのでしょうか?

pythonだと

```
import mymodule
import importlib

importlib.reload(mymodule) # 変更が反映される
```

とするとモジュールの変更が反映されますが

rubyだとどうするのでしょうか?

```
>> load "./big_step.rb" #2回目
TypeError: superclass mismatch for class Number
```

big_step.rb

```
class Number < Struct.new(:value)
    def to_s
        return value.to_s
    end

    def evaluate(environment)
        self
    end

    def inspect
        return "<<#{self}>>"
    end
end


class Multiply < Struct.new(:left, :right)
    def to_s
        return "#{left} * #{right}"
    end

    def inspect
        return "<<#{self}>>"
    end

    def evaluate(environment)
        Number.new(left.evaluate(environment).value * right.environment(environment).value)
    end
end

class Add < Struct.new(:left, :right)
    def to_s
        return "#{left} + #{right}"
    end

    def inspect
        return "<<#{self}>>"
    end

    def evaluate(environment)
        Number.new(left.evaluate(environment).value + right.evaluate(environment).value)
    end
end

class Boolean < Struct.new(:value)
    def to_s
         value.to_s
    end

    def inspect
        "<<#{self}>>"
    end

    def evaluate(environment)
        self
    end
end

class LessThan < Struct.new(:left, :right)
    def to_s
        "#{left} < #{right}"
    end

    def inspect
        "<<#{self}>>"
    end

end

class Variable < Struct.new(:name)
    def to_s
        name.to_s
    end

    def inspect
        "<<#{self}>>"
    end

    def evaluate(environment)
        environment[name]
    end
end

class DoNothing
    def to_s
        "do-noting"
    end

    def inspect
        "<<#{self}>>"
    end

    def ==(other_statement)
        other_statement.instance_of?(DoNothing)
    end
end


class Assign < Struct.new(:name, :expression)
    def to_s
        "#{name} = #{expression}"
    end

    def inspect
        "<<#{self}>>"
    end

    def evaluate(environment)
        environment.merge({name => expression.evaluate(environment)})
    end
end


class If < Struct.new(:condition, :true_exe, :false_exe)
    def to_s
        "if (#{condition}) { #{true_exe} } else { #{false_exe} }"
    end

    def inspect
        "<<#{self}>>"
    end

    def evaluate(environment)
        case condition.evaluate(environment)
        when Boolean.new(true)
            true_exe.evaluate(environment)
        when Boolean.new(false)
            false_exe.evaluate(environment)
        end
    end
end

class Sequence < Struct.new(:first, :second)
    def to_s
        "#{first}; #{second}"
    end

    def inspect
        "<<#{self}>>"
    end


    def evaluate(environment)
        second.evaluate(first.evaluate(environment))
    end
end


class While < Struct.new(:condition, :body)
    def to_s
        "while (#{condition}) { #{body} }"
    end

    def inspect
        "<<#{self}>>"
    end

    def evaluate(environment)
        case condition.evaluate(environment)
        when Boolean.new(true)
            evaluate(body.evaluate(environment))
        when Boolean.new(false)
            environment
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

2回loadすると`class Number < Struct.new(:value)`が2回実行されますが、`Struct.new(:value)`はそれぞれ別のクラスを新しく生成して返すので、クラス定義を追加するときに間違ったスーパークラスを指定したことになりエラーが発生します。

```
irb(main):001:0> Struct.new(:value)
=> #<Class:0x00000000aab338>
irb(main):002:0> Struct.new(:value)
=> #<Class:0x00000000a9fb28>
irb(main):003:0> Struct.new(:value)
=> #<Class:0x00000000a90790>
irb(main):004:0> Struct.new(:value) == Struct.new(:value)
=> false
```

http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/1.9.3/doc/spec=2fdef.html#class

> クラスが既に定義されているとき、さらに同じクラス名でクラス定義を書くとクラスの定義の追加になります。ただし、元のクラスと異なるスーパークラスを指定すると TypeError が発生します。
>
> ```
> class Foo < Array
>   def foo
>   end
> end
>
> # 定義を追加(スーパークラス Array を明示的に指定しても同じ)
> class Foo
>   def bar
>   end
> end
>
> # 間違ったスーパークラスを指定するとエラー
> class Foo < String
> end
> # => superclass mismatch for class Foo (TypeError)
> ```

Comment: 2回目でもうまく読み込まれるようにする方法はありますか?

Comment: `load`ではなく`require`を使えば単純に2回目は無視されますが、それではダメでしょうか？

Comment: 1度 load した後にあるclassの内容を変更した場合、それをirbに反映させるにはどうすればいいのでしょうか?

Answer (score 2):

いくつか対策を考えました。

1. Strict.newしたサブクラスを定数に入れて、1度だけ作成する。
   定数を作ってあるかはdefinde?でチェックします。

   ```
   unless defined? Struct_value
     Struct_value = Struct.new(:value)
   end
   class Number < Struct_value
    # 以下略
   ```
2. クラスが定義されている場合は、未定義にしてから定義する。
   参照: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11503558/how-to-undefine-class-in-ruby
   参照: http://www.iwazer.com/~iwazawa/diary/2013/05/ruby-remove-defined-class.html
   参照: http://qiita.com/ogawatti/items/0e69125ef4155241f598

   ```
   if defined? Number
     Object.send(:remove_const, :Number)
   end
   class Number < Struct.new(:value)
    # 以下略
   ```
3. シングルトンなStructファクトリーを作る。
   コードは結構適当なので、参考程度にしてください。

   ```
   require 'singleton'
   class StructFactory
     include Singleton
     def initialize
       @structs = {}
     end
     def [](*key)
       unless @structs.has_key?(key)
         @structs[key] = Struct.new(*key)
       end
       return @structs[key]
     end
     def self.[](*key)
       instance[*key]
     end
   end
   class Number < StructFactory[:value]
    # 以下略
   ```